# Smartsheet API Email Recipients

Tags: vb.net, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Apologies for the basic question, but how do I add multiple recipients (email addresses) to an email object with the Smartsheet VB (uses C#) SDK?

Documentation here but cant see how to add multiples:
http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#email-object

Comment: The first line of the documentation says _sendTo Recipient[] Array of Recipient Objects. Required._ I think you overlooked that it takes in array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code example shows how to specify two recipients, construct an email object, and execute the `SendSheet` operation using that email object. The same technique for specifying recipients and constructing the email object can be applied to other **Send** operations (e.g., `SendReport`, `SendRow`, etc.).

```
// Specify recipients
Recipient[] recipients = new Recipient[] {
  new Recipient { Email = "john.doe@smartsheet.com" },
  new Recipient { Email = "jane.doe@smartsheet.com" }
};

// Configure email
SheetEmail sheetEmail = new SheetEmail {
  SendTo = recipients,
  Subject = "Check this sheet out!",
  Message = "Here's the sheet I mentioned in our meeting.",
  CcMe = false,
  Format = SheetEmailFormat.PDF,
  FormatDetails = new FormatDetails { PaperSize = PaperSize.A4 }
};

// Send sheet via email
smartsheet.SheetResources.SendSheet(SHEET_ID, sheetEmail);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kim. Trying to do it in VB, but this helps.